# next.js simple routing menu

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, next.js

How do i create a simple routing menu that doesnt navigate away from the menu on link selection - very similar to default action of BrowserRouter in React?

I am reading up on Routing in Next.js but simple examples are not immediately apparent. The [guide on links](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/navigate-between-pages/using-link) only covers complete replacement of the active component with the selected link. I want to add a component into a view not replace everything on screen.

This is working in vanilla React and I need equivalent functionality in Next.js i.e. simple links menu to load components into view.

```
        import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react- router-dom";

    export function MyNavbar() {
    return (
      <Nav>
      <Link to="/" activeClassName="active">
      <NavItem>Home</NavItem>
      </Link>
      <Link to="/about" activeClassName="active">
      <NavItem>Home</NavItem>
      </Link>
      </Nav>
    );
    }

    export default function Home() {
      return (
        <Router>
        <div>
        <MyNavbar></MyNavbar>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/about" component={About} />  
        </div>
        </Router>
      );
    }
```

This does what I expect it to and loads the component into view and does not replaces the entire page (like the next.js examples).

Thanks

Comment: I have created a page wrapper component to contain the navbar and props.children of any components I want to select from the navbar and this creates a reasonable web/app scope navbar. However I'm not clear if this is the "React" way or best way of doing it.

Comment: Why do you want to do that ? What is your specific usecase that requires a frontend routing ? If you want to have a `home` and a `about` page with a navigation panel on the side, you can definitely achieve that with next.js routing system.

Answer (score 0):

Having researched further my comment above is is the recommended Next.js way...

"...page wrapper component to contain the navbar and props.children of any components I want to select from the navbar and this creates a reasonable web/app scope navbar"

Answer (score 0):

NextJS has a route mechanism based on pages concept, and uses the folder calls **pages** as the root of routes, using subfolders in an automatic mechanism to generate nested routes.
When a file is added to the pages folder, a route with the name of this file is automatically generated (you only have to make a **export default** of this file and the magic happens).
Using the pages directory as a reference, just add the files and subdirectories from that directory, see in the example below that index.js inside the pages folder will cause the main route to call this file.

Given the pages folder with the **index.js** file inside, it will be the root path:`pages/index.js` routes to `/`

Subfolders will be paths nested within the pages: `pages / blog / index.js` routes to `/blog`